# Al iniciar varias ventanas en una aplicacion WPF no da arranque y el consumo de ram aumenta

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Estoy haciendo una apliacion WPF con una conexion a base de datos sql, En una sola ventana puse un menu  con al menos 6 botones y un frame para que con cada boton cambie de pagina en el frame pero al inicilizar las distintas paginas en la ventana donde se encuntra el menu el programa no arranca, queria saber si se puede precargar estas paginas antes de iniciar el programa para que el arranque no tenga problema o alguna solucion para poder utilizar todas las paginas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No esta manejado debidamente las herencia de padre a hijo de cada pantalla intenta primero crear un pantalla principal luego dentro de agrega un componente (panel) ese será donde vas insertar cada  pantalla.

Intenta usar UserControl  en vez de WindowsForm eso te ayudara a reducir el rendimiento de tu aplicacion.